# Interfacing Micron Serial NOR Flash Memory

Tags: pi-3, spi

I want to communicate with [Digilent Pmod SF3](https://store.digilentinc.com/pmod-sf3-32-mb-serial-nor-flash/) which contains Micron N25Q256A NOR Flash memory.

I did all the wiring setup between Raspberry Pi and Pmod board as shown below:

```
Pmod      RPi
====      ===
~CS       24
MOSI/DQ0  19
MISO      21
SCK       23
GND       6
VCC       1
W/DQ2     1 (VCC)
HLD/DQ3   1 (VCC)
```

This is a part of the code that I use to interface with SPI Flash memory (adapted from the code in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/24465):

```
def erase_sector(self, addr1, addr2):
        self.write_enable()

        xfer = [SECTOR_ERASE, addr1, addr2, 0]
        self.spi.xfer2(xfer)
        sleep_ms(10)

        self.wait_until_not_busy()
```

I wonder why we need two addresses, namely addr1 and addr2 in order to erase a sector. Shouldn't we send the sector number that we want to erase?

Comment: If you want to know if the code is correct you need to check with the datasheet of the device you want to control.

Comment: Perhaps addr1, addr2 means addrByte1，addByte2, ie, two bytes together makes the complete address or sector number.  Just wild guessing. I have never read the datasheet ．

Comment: @tlfong01 I think you are right. But I'll do a few tests to make sure that.

Comment: Having had a quick look at the code, the only values used in it are zero - as per Joan - I would read the data sheet.  If you reset a control register you may lock yourself out as per the 1-wire memory chips...

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, spi.xfer2() takes a list that includes a COMMAND WORD, ADDRESS (24-bit by default), and DATA, respectively. According to Micron N25Q256A datasheet, one has to send the most significant address byte A[23:16] first and least significant address byte A[7:0] last (as opposed to the program that I took as a [reference](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/24465)):

I've also noticed that you need to erase a sector to be able to write into it.

The test code that I use is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

WREN = 6
WRDI = 4
RDSR = 5
RDSR2 = 0x35
WRSR = 1
READ = 3
WRITE = 2
SECTOR_ERASE = 0xD8
CHIP_ERASE = 0xC7

import sys, struct, os, collections

from array import array
import random

from time import sleep
import spidev
from datetime import datetime

def sleep_ms(msecs):
    sleep(float(msecs) / 1000.0)

class spiflash(object):

    def __init__(self, bus, cs, mode = 0, max_speed_hz = 1000):
        self.spi = spidev.SpiDev()
        self.spi.open(bus,cs)       
        self.spi.max_speed_hz = max_speed_hz
        self.spi.mode = mode

    def __del__(self):
        try:
            self.spi.close()
        except:
            pass

    #reads ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def read_id(self):
         #device_id = self.spi.xfer2([0x9E,0x9F])[1]
         device_id = self.spi.xfer2([0x9E,0x9F,0])[1:]
         
         return device_id
         
    def read_status(self):
        statreg = self.spi.xfer2([RDSR,RDSR])[1]
        #statreg2 = self.spi.xfer2([RDSR2,RDSR2])[1]
        return statreg

    def read_page(self, byte_1, byte_2):
        xfer = [READ, 0, byte_2, byte_1] + [255 for _ in range(256)] # command + 256 dummies
        return self.spi.xfer2(xfer)[4:] #skip 4 first bytes (dummies)

    #writes ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def write_enable(self):
        self.spi.xfer2([WREN])
        sleep_ms(5)

    def write_disable(self):
        self.spi.xfer2([WRDI])
        sleep_ms(5)

    def write_status(self,s1,s2):
        self.write_enable()

        spi.xfer2([WRSR,s1,s2])
        sleep_ms(10)

        self.wait_until_not_busy()

    def write_page(self, byte_1, byte_2, page):
        self.write_enable()

        #print self.read_status()

        xfer = [WRITE, 0, byte_2, byte_1] + page[:256]
        self.spi.xfer2(xfer)
        sleep_ms(10)

        self.wait_until_not_busy()

    def write_and_verify_page(self, addr1, addr2, page):
        self.write_page(addr1, addr2, page)
        return self.read_page(addr1, addr2)[:256] == page[:256]

    #erases ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def erase_sector(self,addr1,addr2):
        self.write_enable()

        xfer = [SECTOR_ERASE, 0, addr2, addr1]
        self.spi.xfer2(xfer)
        sleep_ms(10)

        self.wait_until_not_busy()

    def erase_all(self):
        self.write_enable()

        self.spi.xfer2([CHIP_ERASE])
        sleep_ms(10)

        self.wait_until_not_busy()

    #misc ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def wait_until_not_busy(self):
        statreg = 0x1;
        while (statreg & 0x1) == 0x1:
            #Wait for the chip.
            statreg = self.spi.xfer2([RDSR,RDSR])[1]
            #print "%r \tRead %X" % (datetime.now(), statreg)
            sleep_ms(5)

    #helpers -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def print_status(self,status):
        print "status %s %s" % (bin(status[1])[2:].zfill(8), bin(status[0])[2:].zfill(8))   

    def print_page(self, page):
        s = ""
        for row in range(16):
            for col in range(16):
                s += "%02X " % page[row * 16 + col]
            s += "\n"
        print s 


#TESTS -------------------------------------------------------------------
#TESTS -------------------------------------------------------------------

chip = spiflash(bus = 0, cs = 0)

DEBUG = 1

print "erasing chip"
chip.erase_all()
print "chip erased"

program = []
page_number = 0
byte_number = 0

program_data = array('B')

file_size = os.path.getsize('icebreaker_fw.bin')

#print file_size
with open('icebreaker_fw.bin', 'rb') as f:
    program_data.fromfile(f, file_size)

# pad the last page with zero
if (file_size % 256) != 0:
    for i in range(file_size,(file_size + (256 - (file_size % 256)))):
        program_data.append(0)

temp_file_size = file_size
                              
while temp_file_size >= 0:

    page_data = program_data[page_number*256:page_number*256+256].tolist()
    
    if DEBUG == 1:
        print "Page content:"
        chip.print_page(page_data)

    print "Writing to page ", page_number
    chip.write_and_verify_page(0,page_number,page_data)

    print "Reading page ", page_number, " back"
    page_readback_data = chip.read_page(0,page_number)

    if DEBUG == 1:
        print "Actual page content: PAGE[", page_number, "]" 
        chip.print_page(page_readback_data)

    page_data.sort()
    page_readback_data.sort()
    if page_data != page_readback_data:
        print "MISMATCH between actual and expected content for page ", page_number
        sys.exit(0)

    # CAUTION: second byte of page address is set to zero. i.e., page_number never exceeds 255
    page_number += 1
    temp_file_size -= 256

print "Successfully write the data to Flash memory."
```